# ExactTarget error during mail sending using Fuel API

Tags: marketing-cloud

Hi I'm using this code for sending email but getting error at this line:

```
PostReturn postESDLResponse = postESDL.Post();
```

in this:

```
public static bool CreateEmailDefinition(string emailKey, int ListId)
    {
        ET_EmailSendDefinition postESDL = new ET_EmailSendDefinition();
        try 
        {
            postESDL.AuthStub = myclient;
            postESDL.Name = "Testemail send";
            postESDL.CustomerKey = (DateTime.Now.Day + DateTime.Now.Year + DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Second + DateTime.Now.Millisecond).ToString()+"SendDefKey"; 
            postESDL.Description = "Created with Fuel SDK";
            //postESDL.SendClassification = new ET_SendClassification() { CustomerKey = SendClassificationCustomerKey };
            postESDL.SendDefinitionList = new ET_SendDefinitionList[] { new ET_SendDefinitionList() { List = new ET_List() { ID = ListId }, DataSourceTypeID = DataSourceTypeEnum.List } };
            postESDL.Email = new ET_Email() { ID = 153 };
            PostReturn postESDLResponse = postESDL.Post();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Common.errorHandler("ETarget.Components.ETHelper.CreateEmailDefinition", ex);
        }
        return SendEmailDefinition(postESDL);
    }
    public static bool SendEmailDefinition(ET_EmailSendDefinition ed)
    {
        ed.AuthStub = myclient;
        //ed.CustomerKey = NewSendDefinitionName;
        PerformReturn sendESDResponse = ed.Send();
        return sendESDResponse.Status;
    }
```

Error:

> There was an error in serializing body of message CreateRequest:
>   'There was an error generating the XML document.'

Please help.

Comment: How sure are you of your authentication logic?  Is the myclient piece working well?

Comment: Are you using the version of the FuelSDK-CSharp from the Dot9 branch? or an earlier version?

Answer (score 0):

For those hitting this issue in the future:

Try replacing `List = new ET_List()` with `List = new FuelSDK.List()`.

The way to debug this kind of error is to keep expanding the `InnerException` ti get to the underlying error:

> The type `FuelSDK.ET_List` was not expected. Use the `XmlInclude` or
>   `SoapInclude` attribute to specify types that are not known statically.